# IBM WCM - Content not reflecting for logged-in users

Tags: websphere, wcm, ibm-wcm

I updated content in WCM for both Secured and Public users with 2 links. For public users, those 2 links will be just a text, and for secured user, that would be a link. Though changes are reflecting for public users, still for logged-in users contents are not being displayed.
--Tried for JVM restart of both Application and DMGR.
--Checked in WCM whether changes are properly added or not